# Can i build a phonegap plugin using xamarin

Tags: xamarin, phonegap-plugins

someone asked a similar question 2 years ago, but 2 years is a lot of time in the app world. So I wanted to ask again:

Can I write a plugin (that for example controles the camera) with xamarin using c# to avoid using java/objective c and use this plugin in my html app ?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Xamarin is not setup to create libraries that are then used by native applications. It's theoretically possible but not something they have prioritized.

In the case of Xamarin Android in particular, the entire concept relies on the Mono Framework being present in the app container to handle the .Net/Mono side of the architecture. So doing something like this would require somehow embedding the Mono runtime in your native Java Android application.